# Will Intel's MPX extension make C/C++ completely safe to use?

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, c++, format-string

This is apparently an extension that will eliminate buffer overflow and format string vulnerabilities in C/C++ programs, I would guess by providing hardware support for, e.g. converting `scanf` to `fgets` automatically, or something along those lines.  Will this extension change C/C++'s reputation as a dangerous language?  Will C/C++ finally be completely safe to use?  Or will other vulnerabilities like integer overflows still be a concern?  Is there any reason why MPX wouldn't turn C/C++ into a completely safe language?  I'm not very familiar with MPX and I want to hear from people who are.

I apologize if this question is too general.  Suggestions for narrowing it down are welcome.

Comment: Per section 2.5 "INTEL INSTRUCTION SET ARCHITECTURE AND FEATURES REMOVED" of the Nov 2020 Intel manuals, Intel is removing MPX from 2019 onward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, C++ has enough degrees of freedom that a computer *cannot* make it completely safe. C++ literally gives you full access to anything the CPU can do.

Functions like fscanf are just routines that do looping and checking internally to give you higher-level functionality. However, fscanf has no knowledge of how far a buffer goes (I.e. how big it is). The only part of the code that *does* have that information is the malloc library, but that's also just a higher-level algorithm to make things easier that the hardware doesn't know about.

Theoretically, the compiler can store this information and pass it to the MPX extensions, but in many applications that will be nearly impossible to do because most things are stored as `void*` and passed around manually so a static analyzer cannot have the requisite information to set those registers. The only way to do this would be to store additional information at runtime, thereby changing the size of `void*` which would violate the rules of C++, so it would have to be a special type that very few developers will actually implement because it will cost too much.

A buffer overflow happens when the developer is lazy with their power, not when the hardware messes up.

This is just *one* of the possible bugs in software that make it insecure. There have been SEVERAL bugs which are integer overflows, invalid logic, etc.

So no, it will not make C++ completely safe to use - nothing will.